# Print DevExpress Datagrid in custom format

Tags: wpf, printing, datagrid, devexpress

I want to print the data grid in the following format

> Username
>   Address
>   City
>   PinCode

Eg :

> JohnSmith
>   25,NewStreet
>   New York
>   75896

These are my datagrid columns columns

**UserName, Address, City, PinCode**

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition as my backend and DevExpress Product gridcontrol as my datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DevExpress.VerticalGrig.VGridControl and you can get the requirements you want to view your data vertically.

Get your data from the Database as a datatable and set the datasource property value to the datatable.

For the VgridView you just have to add the rows and name or bound the rows with DataFieldName.

Answer (score 0):

Marina told me that she answered this question in the support center.  So, I will just post a link here for the community:

[Print datagrid in custom format](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q314771)